# my website redirected by someone else

Tags: hijacked

First of all i cant find true forum to post ,but i need a very quick help.

I have registered a domain name with godaddy couple of days ago , but today, after i post my domain name for appraisal, it was redirecting to another domain name with just diffrent tld. extension

Am i hacked?

How can i resolve this problem?

(domain manager shows its already parked to godaddy there is no problem with name servers they are allright but still redirecting the domain)

windsurf.ws redirecting to windsurf.lv

Comment: When I go to windsurd.ws it takes me to a holding page for worldsite.ws. Did you type the URL correctly?

Comment: @paulmorriss windsurf.ws sorry

Comment: Hmm -- I was redirected to google.com. Show us your DNS records 9GoDaddy -> DNS Management).

Answer (score 1):

It looks more like your DNS records are not set up properly, GoDaddy Support should be able to help you set them up.  And remember that propagation can take some time.

Answer (score 0):

for me it shows an error

```
Error 105 (net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED): Unable to resolve the server's DNS address.
```

yes there is something wrong with your DNS records.

but it doesn't seem to be a serious issue, Godaddy support can resolve it.