# website dns redirects to another

Tags: dns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [my website redirected by someone else](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16395/my-website-redirected-by-someone-else)

First of all i cant find true forum to post ,but i need a very quick help.

I have registered a domain name with godaddy couple of days ago , but today, after i post my domain name for appraisal, it was redirecting to another domain name with just diffrent tld. extension

Am i hacked?

How can i resolve this problem?

(domain manager shows its already parked to godaddy there is no problem with name servers they are allright but still redirecting the domain)

Comment: What is the domain? 
Where is it redirecting to? 
Does the domain have any hosting attached to it - if so, have you set that up correctly?

Comment: @micheal windsurf.ws redirects to windsurf.ly domain on a godaddy hosting

Comment: @micheal i can send email but still www redirects

Comment: Ran it though http://web-sniffer.net/

Status: HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.windsurf.lv

Refer to GoDaddy.

Comment: @drazisil what s the solution now?

Comment: Exact dupe(due to posting across multiple sites).